# IIS 7.5 not rolling over logs hourly

Tags: iis, logging, iis-7.5

I have six IIS 7.5 web servers deployed using a Shared Configuration. The properties for the logging in the configuration are set to log Per Site, W3C, and on an hourly schedule:

[image]

For five of the web servers, this works correctly. However for one web server it is still logging as if it was set to a daily schedule.

I have tried restarting W3SVC and the WPAS service as these two usually resolve strange issues like this, but alas: no luck.

This affects all the websites that are configured on that server. All the websites on all the other servers log correctly.

Is there something that's server-specific that could be overriding this setting?

Answer (score 0):

Logging schedule set in IIS server globally will be applicable to all sites hosted on same IIS. If you change the schedule at server global level it will be applied to all sites automatically.

If you have already set it to Hourly at server level, you should make sure that it is not set to daily for any particular site manually.